# Error in admin panel: MySQL server has gone away

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, database, error

Last night in my Admin panel suddenly stopped working.

The problem it shows:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away, query was: SELECT `core_flag`.* FROM `core_flag` WHERE
>   (`core_flag`.`flag_code`='synchronize')
>
> Trace: 
>   /home/zolshopc/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
>   /home/zolshopc/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291):
>   Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
>   /home/zolshopc/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480):
>   Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
>   /home/zolshopc/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `core_fl...', Array)
>
>   /home/zolshopc/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504):
>
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT`core_fl...', Array)
>   /home/zolshopc/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(756):
>   Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
>   /home/zolshopc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(380):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
>   /home/zolshopc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Core_Model_File_Storage_Flag), 'synchronize', 'flag_code')
>   /home/zolshopc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Flag.php(119):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load('synchronize', 'flag_code')
>   /home/zolshopc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Storage.php(84):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Flag->loadSelf()
>   /home/zolshopc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Observer.php(47):
>   Mage_Core_Model_File_Storage->getSyncFlag()
>   /home/zolshopc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Observer->addSynchronizeNotification(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
>   /home/zolshopc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Observer), 'addSynchronizeN...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
>   /home/zolshopc/public_html/app/Mage.php(448):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
>   /home/zolshopc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(529):
>   Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
>   /home/zolshopc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
>   /home/zolshopc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407):
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
>   /home/zolshopc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
>   /home/zolshopc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>   /home/zolshopc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>   /home/zolshopc/public_html/app/Mage.php(684):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>   /home/zolshopc/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
>   {main}

My server swn try to raise the `max_allowed_packet` but its not help.
What to do?

tnx

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to the site! One thing that you may not be aware of is that the question editor formats the # character as a heading, so your post looks like it has a lot of headings. The solution is to use a code block, by indenting the text four spaces.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544913/sqlstatehy000-general-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away-magento) the similar problem is described.